# Qt6 compiler binary package

Tags: ubuntu, packages, qt, repository

I'm aware I can cross-compile Qt6 on my dev machine or I can build the Qt6 from sources directly on the Rapsberry Pi.

But is there any binary package for the compiler? Like when you use the online installer on a destkop environment?

I'm trying Ubuntu Server on RPi 3 B+

Answer (score 0):

It is in Debian Bookworm (and will be) in Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm.

I am not sure about Ubuntu - also why would want it on a Server?

NOTE the easy way to find this (or any other package) on your system is `apt search qt6`

Comment: The usual qt6* packages are for headers or runtime libraries, aren't they? What is the name for the "kit" (compiler + debugger)?

Comment: I'm trying Ubuntu Server because I don't need X (I'd use the framebuffer, like eglfs)